# Trying to add pandas to aws lambda without numpy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have been trying to import pandas into aws lambda, but am running into size issues since I need to import one more module into aws lambda. I notice when I package pandas into a lambda compatible zip file, even if I install without dependencies in pip using pip install --no-deps, there is always a numpy install within pandas since pandas testing requires numpy.

Is there anyway to pip install pandas without any numpy at all? Numpy is a huge package--81 mb and it would be great to get rid of it as aws already has a prebuilt scipy numpy layer.

Pandas zipped project dir

```
Python:
        Pandas
        numpy
        pandas-dist...
        numpy-dist...
        dateutil...
        etc.
```

For reference, I have been following this guide:
https://medium.com/@qtangs/creating-new-aws-lambda-layer-for-python-pandas-library-348b126e9f3e

Comment: Have you tried recently launched EFS integration? This can potentially solve the size issue. https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/aws/new-a-shared-file-system-for-your-lambda-functions/

Comment: i've tried it, but it looks really expensive. $6/mb per month for provisioned concurrency.

Comment: Is it possible to do with s3? I'm thinking I can upload a package into s3, and then import from s3 to aws lambda. Just not sure how to import.

Comment: yeah, it is possible. You can download to `/tmp` directory and you will need to set PYTHONPATH before you import the library.

Comment: do you have any examples of how I can do that? I assume tmp is only temporary so I wouldn't want to download to tmp every time I run my lambda.